# JObject.ToObject overwrites properties how can I merge instead?

Tags: c#, json.net

I am using two Document queries that together fills all properties in a C# object.

They are returned as JObjects from the DB so I am using JObject.ToObject() in order to map the JSON to the C# object.

The problem is that this works great for the first query but when I do it for the second query, it overwrites and creates a new object instead of merging with the existing one.

I Understand this is desired behavior but how can I merge the second ToObject() call so that it does not overwrite the existing properties ?

Comment: How would you expect the merge to work? Which properties should be overwritten and which shouldn't?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay They are not overlapping at all, DB query 1 has half of the properties and DB query 2 has the other half so there is no overlap with regards to properties

Comment: In that case you can [populate an object](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PopulateObject.htm).

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [How can I populate an existing object from a JToken (using Newtonsoft.Json)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30220328/3744182), agree?  Or do you have some additional requirement to control exactly which properties get overwritten?

Comment: @dbc looks like it yes